# Read local compressed XML file(gzip) in Android application

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, gzip

I don't know how to get an `InputStream`(Read gzipped local xml file) from the locally stored `gzip xml` file.

**employee.gz**

If someone Can help I really appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link works with zip. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/unzip-files-in-android.html

I am not sure if it will work with gz files, but you could give it a try. There's a documentation on GZIPInputStream class on the dev docs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html

This piece of code works.

```
GZIPInputStream inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(
                        "path to file")));

String str = IOUtils.convertStreamToString(inputStream);
```

I have used a util class which converts the input stream to a string. You might want to do the reading part manually.

Comment: I tried that code. but I am getting FileNotFound Exception. I got the path from right click the GzipXML file which resides on raw folder and by properties PATH. Is that not the path???

Comment: I have tried it with the file in SDCard, and it works. There's probably some problem getting the file from raw or assets. I am not sure about that, but it does work if the file is on sdcard. If you could figure out how to get around the FileNotFound Exception, it should be fine.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll check. may be because it resides in raw folder

Comment: @JibW is it because of assets folder?